# Accessing "getState" from within action creator using redux-thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `mapDispatchToProps` function like this one below.

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {
    handleChangeLang: changeLocaleDispatcher(dispatch),
    handleChange: handleChangeDispatcher(dispatch),
    handleSubmit: handleSubmitDispatcher(dispatch)
  }
}
```

I just added `redux-thunk` to my project so I can access `state` from my action creators (think that's the correct term).

It doesn't seem there's any documentation in `redux-thunk` outlining how to access `getState` from `mapDispatchToProps`. The docs `dispatch` using the `store.dispatch` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial syntax is wrong, and the "hacky" example is also not how you should go about it.

A sample would look like:

```
import {thunkAction1, thunkAction2} from "myActions";
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";

const mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) => {
    return {
        manuallyBoundAction : (...args) => dispatch(thunkAction1(...args)),
        autoBoundAction : bindActionCreators(thunkAction2, dispatch),
        multipleActionsTogether : bindActionCreators({thunkAction1, thunkAction2}, dispatch)
    }
};
```

And no, `getState` itself is not accessible inside `mapDispatchToProps`.  It's available inside the thunk, but not `mapDispatch`.

You may want to read [this answer on why thunks exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559), as well as the Redux docs on [async actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html).

Answer (score 0):

So while I don't see your current action creator in your question, I will assume it's ES6/ES2015 javascript.

The below should give you freedom to grab any state. Since you have `redux-thunk`, you should be good to go.

```
export function setActivity(activityName) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ACTIVITY,
      description: 'Set the name of the activity being done now',
      currentActivityName: activityName,
      currentActivityData: getState().activityStore.activities[activityName]
    });
  };
}
```

**activityStore** is same as what you've defined for that particular reducer, see below.

```
export const reducers = {
  activityStore: ActivityStore.reducer,
  someOtherStore: SomeOtherStore.reducer
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Hacky fix :/

```
let ProvidedApp = (serverProps) => {

  let store = getStore(serverProps)

  let ConnectedApp = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps(store)
  )(App)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedApp/>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(store) {
  return (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
      handleChangeLang: store.dispatch(changeLocaleDispatcher),
      handleChange:  store.dispatch(handleChangeDispatcher),
      handleSubmit: store.dispatch(handleSubmitDispatcher)
    }
  }
}
```